# How to create instance of struct in Objective-C that was defined in C file

Tags: objective-c, c

In Xcode I have C classes that contains the following definition:

```
typedef struct {
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
    CoordUnit unit;
} YG
#define YGMeterPoint(x,y,z) __YGPointWithUnit(x,y,z,METER)
```

This used as follows in C:

```
//Declares origin point and translated point
YGPoint point = YGMeterPoint(994272.661, 113467.422);

//Converts point in Lambert Zone 1 to WGS84
point = YGPointConvertWGS84(point, LAMBERT_I)

//Convert to Degree
point = YGPointToDegree(point);

printf("Lat:%.9f - Lon:%.9f", point.y, point.x);
```

But I would like call it using Objective-C in Xcode. How to do that?

Comment: Objective-C is a strict superset of C, so where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Martin R said, normally I can't see why you would need/want to do this however [this article](https://github.com/typhoon-framework/Typhoon/wiki/wrap-primitive-values-into-NSValue) explains how to do it. Look at Example 2.